# Install OpenCV opencv 4.7.0_6 to Apple M1 Pro (jar and dylib missing)

Tags: opencv, jar, ant, dylib

As the title says, java jar and dylib not getting created after installing the opencv. I also tried cmake with source code but got the same result. Any idea about this?

Steps taken

- brew install ant
- brew install --build-from-source opencv
- brew postinstall opencv

**% brew info opencv**

==> opencv: stable 4.7.0 (bottled)
Open source computer vision library
https://opencv.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.7.0_6 (864 files, 123.1MB)

**% brew info ant**

==> ant: stable 1.10.13 (bottled), HEAD
Java build tool
https://ant.apache.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ant/1.10.13 (1,669 files, 45.5MB)